# Calling different functions based on type

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do something along these lines

```
template<typename T>
bool FetchVal(T & fetchedData)
{
   //Get data from some function
   dataAsString = Get();

   // based on type of T call
   fetchedData = ConvertToDouble(dataAsString);
   //or
   fetchedData = ConvertToInt(dataAsString); 
   //and so on
}
```

Is this possible using templates and if yes how?

**EDIT:** Basically I am parsing an XML, in the get for a tag and that string now needs to be converted to int/double/... based on what was the expected type(i.e. type of fetchedData) hope this makes it clear.

David has given an answer and it indeed should work. Is there any more elegant way(if possible without using typeid, as I remember having read somewhere that this call can cause a performance hit)?

Comment: A little more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish would help a lot here.

Comment: XML is notoriously difficult to parse. Just find an off-the-shelf parser to use.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Arun check my solution for generic implementation, you can create something on that lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way to do what you want uses output parameters:

```
template<typename T>
bool FetchVal(T & fetchedData)
{
   // Get data from some function
   dataAsString = Get();

   Convert(dataAsString, fetchedData);
}
```

then, just have as many implementations of Convert as you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
bool FetchVal(T & fetchedData)
{
   //Get data from some function
   dataAsString = Get();

   stringstream ss(dataAsString);
   ss >> fetchdData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates as:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{

  public:

    void fnX(const string& data){cout<<" in X "<<data<<endl;}

};


class Y{

  public:

    void fnY(const string& data){cout<<" in Y "<<data<<endl;}

};

typedef void (X::*FnXType)(const string&);

typedef void (Y::*FnYType)(const string&);

template<typename T, typename Fnc>
bool FetchVal(T & fetchedData, Fnc fnc)
{
   //Get data from some function
   //dataAsString = Get();
   string dataAsString("data");

   (fetchedData.*fnc)(dataAsString);
}

int main()
{
    X objX;
    FnXType fncX = &X::fnX;
    FetchVal<X, FnXType>(objX, fncX);

    Y objY;
    FnYType fncY = &Y::fnY;
    FetchVal<Y, FnYType>(objY, fncY);

}
```